# Example of topologically mixing dynamics on R

Tags: dynamical-systems

What is the simplest example of a topologically mixing dynamical system on R? The only examples I know, the space is compact.

Comment: What does $R$ represent in this question?

Comment: It must be the real line.

Comment: of course real line